# Dynamic column height in free form powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to get height of my auto size column to re allign other columns in freeform datawindow

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? I found this with a quick google search:

http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C508e4eeb.65c9.1681692777@sybase.com%3E

Comment: This gives you the height of the row, does this help?: `dw_1.describe("Evaluate('rowheight()', "+string(dw_1.getrow())+")")`

Comment: No it is giving me row height not the column ones